# Easy mode of titlesec not working with beamerarticle

Tags: titlesec, beamerarticle

I can't get the "easy" mode of `titlesec` to work with `beamerarticle`.

With the following example:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\RequirePackage{beamerarticle}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\end{document}
```

I get the error message:

```
test-beamerarticle.tex:5: Package titlesec Error: Not allowed in `easy' settings.
test-beamerarticle.tex:6: Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@si was complete.
test-beamerarticle.tex:14: Missing number, treated as zero.
test-beamerarticle.tex:14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
test-beamerarticle.tex:14: Missing number, treated as zero.
test-beamerarticle.tex:14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

If I use the less easy form, with:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\RequirePackage{beamerarticle}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesection}{1em}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\end{document}
```

The document compiles but with the message:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty: [titlesec] Non standard sectioning command detected Using default spacing and no format. (page 1)
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty: [titlesec] Non standard sectioning command detected Using default spacing and no format. (page 1)
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty: [titlesec] Non standard sectioning command detected Using default spacing and no format. (page 1)
```

It's not a problem for me since I only want to change the shape and size, and not the spacing of format but is there a way around this conflict ?

Comment: To be honest, it shouldn't be too surprising this doesn't work. Beamer redefines things fairly significantly and even `beamerarticle` has to support very different syntax etc. `titlesec` is obviously designed to customise standard definitions and will have problems with many non-standard versions. I think this is just a fact of life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make the redefinitions before `beamerarticle` acts:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\end{document}
```

The result (the compilation goes with no warnings and no errors):

[image]